# Converting Yolov8 Model to Onnx and used it in OpenCV [IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable]

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolov8

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the ONNX model
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX("best.onnx")

# Load an image from your dataset
image = cv2.imread("image3.jpg")

# Preprocess the image (resize, normalize, etc.) according to YOLOv8's requirements
# You may need to adjust these preprocessing steps based on the specific requirements of your YOLOv8 model
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 640))
resized_image = resized_image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
resized_image = np.transpose(resized_image, (2, 0, 1))
resized_image = np.expand_dims(resized_image, axis=0)

# Set the preprocessed image as input to the model
model.setInput(resized_image)

# Perform inference
output = model.forward()

# YOLOv8 output format is typically a list of detections, where each detection has:
# - class probabilities (index 5 to the end)
# - objectness score (index 4)
# - bounding box coordinates (index 0 to 3)

# Loop through the detections
for detection in output[0, 0]:
    scores = detection[5:]  # Get the class probabilities
    class_id = np.argmax(scores)  # Get the class with the maximum probability
    confidence = scores[class_id]

    # Check for helmet class (assuming class ID 0 for helmets) and a confidence threshold
    if class_id == 0 and confidence > 0.5:  # Adjust confidence threshold as needed
        x, y, w, h = (detection[0:4] * np.array([image.shape[1], image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[0]])).astype(int)

        # Draw the bounding box
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, "Helmet", (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display or save the image with bounding boxes
cv2.imshow("Helmet Detection", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using my helmet detection model weights to predict class label and bounding box around the picture using opencv but it give me the error that
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/arhamriaz/Desktop/opencvmodel/main.py", line 30, in 
scores = detection[5:]  # Get the class probabilities
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.